# trying to touch an item in an array not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have An Array inside my touches began method (I would like to be able to touch the sprite
and for it to NSlog the touch) is there something im forgetting to do or am doing something wrong?

I can log the touch on the screen but when I touch the bubbles nothing happens.
any help would be great.

```
-(id) init
{ 
if((self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(10, 10, 10,10)]) )  //sand 101, 116, 88
{
    size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    self.touchEnabled = YES;

 //other stuff here

Bubble01 = [[Bubble alloc]initWithBubbleWithLabel:@"_Bubble.png" opacity:255     gloss:@"_Bubble_overlay.png" posX:0 posY:0 data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",     [Sortingarray objectAtIndex:BubbleAnswerBubble_1_IndexValue]]];
    Bubble02 = [[Bubble alloc]initWithBubbleWithLabel:@"_Bubble.png" opacity:255 gloss:@"_Bubble_overlay.png" posX:0 posY:0 data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Sortingarray objectAtIndex:BubbleAnswerBubble_2_IndexValue]]];
    Bubble03 = [[Bubble alloc]initWithBubbleWithLabel:@"_Bubble.png" opacity:255 gloss:@"_Bubble_overlay.png" posX:0 posY:0 data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Sortingarray objectAtIndex:BubbleAnswerBubble_3_IndexValue]]];
    Bubble04 = [[Bubble alloc]initWithBubbleWithLabel:@"_Bubble.png" opacity:255 gloss:@"_Bubble_overlay.png" posX:0 posY:0 data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Sortingarray objectAtIndex:BubbleAnswerBubble_4_IndexValue]]];
    Bubble05 = [[Bubble alloc]initWithBubbleWithLabel:@"_Bubble.png" opacity:255 gloss:@"_Bubble_overlay.png" posX:0 posY:0 data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Sortingarray objectAtIndex:BubbleAnswerBubble_5_IndexValue]]];
    Bubble06 = [[Bubble alloc]initWithBubbleWithLabel:@"_Bubble.png" opacity:255 gloss:@"_Bubble_overlay.png" posX:0 posY:0 data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Sortingarray objectAtIndex:AnswerBubble_6_IndexValue]]];

//other stuff here

}
return self;
}
```

touchesbegan

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
//set up touches
NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

//log if touches are working if I touch the screen area
NSLog(@"touches screen");

//create an array from bubble class (CCSprites with labels, 
//I need to be able to determine which sprite was touched and run an action on it)

BubbleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:Bubble01,
               Bubble02,
               Bubble03,
               Bubble04,
               Bubble05,
               Bubble06, 
               nil];

    for(int i = 0; i < [BubbleArray count]; i++)
    {

    Bubble *sprite = (Bubble *)[BubbleArray  objectAtIndex:i];

    //create a rect to find the position and size of the sprite 
    //BackBubble is a sprite that i'm using to detect the content size

    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(

           sprite.BackBubble.position.x - (sprite.BackBubble.contentSize.width/2),
           sprite.BackBubble.position.y - (sprite.BackBubble.contentSize.height/2),
           sprite.BackBubble.contentSize.width,
           sprite.BackBubble.contentSize.height);

    //use the rect and touch location to determine hit
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(targetRect, location))

    //this doesn't work possibly because Bubble class is a CClayer?

    //if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], location))
    {
        selectedSprite = sprite;
        NSLog(@"touches bubble sprite");
    }
}
```

}

Any insight would be great to help me understand what i'm doing wrong.
cheers :)

new array code (getting the height and width of the sprite through the custom class

```
 for(int i = 0; i < [DragItems count]; i++)
   {


    Bubble *sprite = (Bubble *)[BubbleArray  objectAtIndex:i];
    location = [sprite convertToNodeSpace:location];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite.BackBubble boundingBox], location))
    {
        selectedSprite = sprite;
           NSLog(@"touches bubble");
    }
   }
```

Bubble.m

```
    #import "Bubble.h"
#import "Common.h"

#define ButtonFlashTime .4
#define KBubbleColourTurqoiseBlueFlash 2323
#define ScrollSpeed 5.2f
#define DecoyTextY 5
#define DecoyTextX -2


@implementation Bubble
@synthesize BackBubble,FrontShine,BubbleLabel,startX,startY,currentY,currentX,isNotTouchActivated,myInt,bubblespeed,tagNumber;  //isTouched

-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    {
        //touches
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
        isNotTouchActivated = false;
        isTouched = NO;

         bubblespeed = 0;

        //start scrolling
        [self MoveWithoutProblem];

        [self setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.5,0.5)];

        BackBubble = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:Bubblepng];
        BackBubble.position = ccp(X,Y);
        [BackBubble setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];
        [self addChild: BackBubble z:5];
        NSLog(@"BackBubble, %f %f",BackBubble.position.x,BackBubble.position.y);

        //other code here

        [self setContentSize:[BackBubble boundingBox].size];

    }
    return self;
}



-(BOOL) isTouchOnSprite:(CGPoint)touch{
    CGPoint local = [self convertToNodeSpace:touch];
    CGRect r = self.boundingBox;
    r.origin = CGPointZero;
    Boolean b = CGRectContainsPoint( r, local );
    //CCLOG(@"touch %f : %f : %d",touch.x,touch.y,b);
    if (b) {
        return YES;
    }else {
        return NO;
    }
}
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPoint];
    if([self isTouchOnSprite:touchPoint]){
        //CGPoint move = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
        isNotTouchActivated = TRUE;
        //isTouched = YES;
         //NSLog(@"isTouched = %@", self.isTouched ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        currentX = touchPoint.x;
        currentY = touchPoint.y;
        self.position = touchPoint;
        return YES;
    }
    // NSLog(@"isTouched = %@", self.isTouched ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    return NO;

}
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPoint];
    if (isNotTouchActivated) {
        currentX = touchPoint.x;
        currentY = touchPoint.y;
        self.position = touchPoint;
    }
}
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    isNotTouchActivated = FALSE;
    //isTouched = NO;
}
-(void)MoveWithoutProblem{


    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    int MaxHeightofBubbles = 350;
    int minHeightofBubbles = 150;
    int RandomNumber = [self generateRandomNumberBetweenMin:minHeightofBubbles Max:MaxHeightofBubbles];
    float ConvertedRandom = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: RandomNumber] floatValue];

    int MaxWidthofBubbles = 0;
    int minWidthofBubbles = 900;
    int RandomNumber02 = [self generateRandomNumberBetweenMin:MaxWidthofBubbles Max:minWidthofBubbles];
    float ConvertedRandom02 = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: RandomNumber02] floatValue];

    startX = ConvertedRandom02;

    startY = ConvertedRandom;

    currentX = startX+myInt;
    currentY = startY;
    self.position = ccp(startX,startY);

    [self schedule:@selector(startMoving)];
}



-(void)startMoving{
    if (!isNotTouchActivated) {



        currentX+=bubblespeed;
        [self setPosition:ccp(currentX,currentY)];
    }

    if (self.position.x >= 1024+50) {
         //NSLog(@"off screen");

        isrestartscrolling = YES;
    }

    if (isrestartscrolling == YES) {
        //[self RandomYPOs];
        [self scheduleOnce:@selector(newRandomX) delay:0.2];
        isrestartscrolling = NO;
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: I don't see where  you add sprites in your scene. [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:<yourobject/view>]; Next [<yourobject/view> addTarget:self action:@selector(yourfunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

Comment: the bubble sprites are added in the init (sorry ill put that code there too)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little hard to read but your immediate problem to why the touch doesn't work is because you are assuming your layer (Bubble) has a content width and height. If you did not set this, it wouldn't have it which is why your commented out line for `[sprite boundingBox]` does not work. Try `[sprite.BackBubble boundingBox]`. Adding items to a layer does not adjust that layer's content size automatically.

Another thing you can try is to add:

```
location = [sprite convertToNodeSpace:location];
```

If your bubble layer or that back bubble is moved at any point then simply adding the back bubble's position to a `CGRect` is not likely to work. Try the first idea first then try this if it doesn't work.

Hope this helped you Natalie.

Comment: Thank-you Allen, hmm sorry that I don't understand... so when I created the "CGRect targetRect" does that not give the width and height of the sprite? (I am new so I am just trying to understand how this all works, I have tried the bounding box solution - but unfortunately that doesn't work (the (Bubble*) layer also handles its own touches (dragging but not collisions) - but its the first time Ive made my own sprite class that does its own touch detection (on the game layer i'm trying to get the collisions to work with another class) - so some teething problems as to how to use it properly

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the `Bubble` instance. Your comment in your code ask if the Bubble's bounding box didn't work because it was a `CCLayer`. Layers don't have their width and height set when you add objects to it unless you specifically give the layer a width and height. That means your `[sprite boundingBox]` would not work since the object, which is a `Bubble` (which is stated to be a layer), would not have a content size.

Comment: Also in your revised code you are not getting the proper results because you are not using the original touch position. With each iteration you are taking a value converted into one Bubble's space and trying to convert it into another Bubble's space, rather than using the original touch position for each calculation. Try something like `CGPoint localLocation = [sprite convertToNodeSpace:location];` and use that in the  `CGRectContainsPoint()` call.

Comment: Also one more thing. I was suggesting doing one or the other, not both. In your OP code you were manually creating a CGRect to test, which converting the touch location into node space would be necessary. If you are just using the bubble back's bounding box property you should be fine since that does a parent transform internally. You should be able to take out the node space converting method and I think it will work. If it does not you can try to debug the code and see what values the touch location and the rects are and see if there is something odd there.

Comment: Hello Allen thank-you for your thoughts on this!, I have changed the Bubble class from CCLayer to CCSprite (In an effort to get content size and touches to register on the game layer) and also tried your suggestion, they do sound right, I just know that Ive probably done something weird with the setup of my class ill update the code, maybe you'll see the mistake